# woocommerce autocomplete billing_address per user per product

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In my Woocommerce store, each product should require from purchasers to use a different `billing_address_1`.

What I am wondering is if there is a way to autocomplete `billing_address_1` with the users previously used `billing_address_1` from prior orders or the most recent order for that specific sku/product.

If it just took the most recently used `billing_address_1`, then it might be associated with another product...

**EDIT**: For example, `user 64` buys product `SKU=1234` from the store, uses a `billing_address_1` for that product. then the same user goes and buys `SKU=4321` and uses a different `billing_address_1` since its a different product. 2 days later, `user 64` decides to purchase `SKU=1234` again. Instead of inputting the `billing_address_1`, I was wondering if its possible autofill this entry with the last known `billing_address_1` for user `user 64` attached to their last order for `SKU=1234`.

FYI - only one product (e.g. SKU) may be purchased at a time on the store.

Comment: Woocommerce already take the last used billing address 1 from the most recent order by default. So You should update your question as when you say *"If it just took the most recently used billing_address_1, then it might be associated with another product..."* is just unclear or not detailed. Where is your question? what are you expecting? for what product? Where is the code that you have tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: If I understand right, you want the last used address from a recent order that contained the same product? regardless of the buyer who purchased it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edits, try this.

**EDIT:** (tested)

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_address_1', 'change_default_checkout_address' );
function change_default_checkout_address($default_billing_address){

    $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
        'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(), //can be any other user id, like in your example = 64
        'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
        'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'sort_order' => 'DESC'
    ) );

    $product_id = false;

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item){
        $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    }

    if (!$product_id) return $default_billing_address;


    foreach ($customer_orders as $order){
        $current_order = new WC_Order($order->ID);

        $order_items = $current_order->get_items();
        foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
            if ($product_id == $order_item['product_id']){
                return $current_order->billing_address_1;
            };

        }

    }

    return $default_billing_address;
}
```

Comment: Hmm... not working (e.g. not autofilling billing_address_1 when I use dummy account that has pre-existing orders of the SKU in cart.) ... but I see where you are going with this

Comment: Ok, fixed the code. was misspelled. Tested on one of my sites and it's working.let me know if it's working for you buddy

Answer (score 0):

I think of another way - add custom field to each product with the default address you wish to fetch and have on checkout. call that custom field "default_product_address".
The following code will run through the cart items, and will take the default address of the *first item*.

```
add_filter( 'default_checkout_billing_address_1', 'change_default_checkout_address' );
function change_default_checkout_address(){
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item){
        return get_post_meta($item['product_id'], 'default_product_address', true);
    }
}
```

(untested)

Comment: I think I am going to add a bit more context to my question as an edit to help explain :)